# FirebaseUser class not downloading / importing

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an Android project linked to Firebase where I am trying to follow the Firebase [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/) to setup Firebase Authentication using the `firebase.auth` package.

**The problem**

I need a `FirebaseUser` variable. But when I try to import using the following import, Android Studio just highlights the `FirebaseUser` part red. When I hover my mouse over it, it says it cannot resolve it. Of course, when I try to declare it inside a class, it goes red.

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
```

**Trying to figure out what is wrong**

On my app level build.gradle file, I have the following dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

So I did import the `firebase-auth` package.

Next, when I check out the gradle external libraries, I have the `FirebaseAuth` class imported under the `classes.jar/com.google/android.gms.internal/firebase.auth` path and a bunch of other classes. However, I don't see a `FirebaseUser` class being imported by gradle.

**Question: what am I doing wrong?**

Some of my hypotheses are:

1. Wrong import statement in `build.gradle` - perhaps wrong version number
2. Gradle is not importing dependencies of dependencies for some reason.

Last note, I have not made any edits on the Manifest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the same version of all Firebase libraries.  You can upgrade `firebase-auth` to 9.8.0 or downgrade `firebase-database` to 9.4.0.

You must also use the matching version of `firebase-ui-database` as defined in the table provided in the [Firebase UI docs](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).  The docs also explain that the UI libs have transitive dependencies on other Firebase libs.  In your case, you can eliminate `firebase-database` from the list.

Example:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest dependencies.
Replace your versions with 11.6.2 of google services and firebase-ui-database:1.0.2 if your compiled version is 26 or later.